# How solve an error in PDF byteString PyPDF2

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I create a function to convert a PDF with many pages in a list of byteString, but with an specific PDF with 1 page there is an strange error, the function return a list and this error:
Invalid stream (index 0) within object 14 0: Stream has ended unexpectedly

But when I try to convert the output to a PDF again using this list with error the PDF is create well and can be open and visualized. But when I try to process this list with de DOCUMENT AI from google it return nothing. With others PDF this error not occurs only with this one in specific.

The functions are:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def pdf_to_list(byte_string: bytes) -> List[bytes]:
    pdf_pages = []
    with io.BytesIO(byte_string) as stream:
        pdf = PdfReader(stream, strict = False)
        num_pages = len(pdf.pages)
        for page_number in range(num_pages):
            pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
            pdf_writer.add_page(pdf.pages[page_number])
            output_stream = io.BytesIO()
            pdf_writer.write(output_stream)
            output_stream.seek(0)
            pdf_pages.append(output_stream.read())
    return pdf_pages

def save_bytestring_as_pdf(bytestring: bytes, file_path: str) -> None:
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(bytestring)
    print(f'Bytestring saved as PDF: {file_path}')
```

Can anyone help me to see what is happening? I have the pdf with problem, but I do not know how to upload the PDF here, but if you want I can send it to test.

Comment: There may be an incomplete *PDF stream* in that *specific PDF with 1 page*.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how relevant this is to your question or use case, would need more information and context about what you are trying to accomplish.

In [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/overview), to send the PDF file as bytes, you don't need to use a library like `PyPDF` to convert to bytes strings. You can follow the example in the following documentation and open it as a binary file to send the bytes like this.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-documents-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

(Snippet of the full code)

```py
    # Read the file into memory
    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()

    # Load binary data
    raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(
        content=image_content,
        mime_type="application/pdf",  # Refer to https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/file-types for supported file types
    )

    # Configure the process request
    # `processor.name` is the full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
    # `projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}`
    request = documentai.ProcessRequest(name=processor.name, raw_document=raw_document)

    result = client.process_document(request=request)
```